# ¿Porque no imprime los resultados?

Tags: python, python-3.x

El programa debe factorizar y mostrar todos los factores primos de un número ingresado por el usuario.

Por ejemplo si el usuario ingresa el número:

```
20
```

Deberia imprimirse en pantalla:

```
2
2
5
```

Pero se ejecuta el programa y no imprime nada en pantalla:

Process finished with exit code 0

```
def detector(num):
    cont = 0
    for i in range(1, num+1):
        if num % i == 0:
            cont += 1
    if cont == 2 or num == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def primeFactorization():

    factor = 2
    number = int(input('Please, choose a number to factorize: '))

    while number != 1 and detector(factor):
        if number % factor == 0:
            yield factor
            number = number / factor
        else:
            factor += 1

primeFactorization()
```

Comment: Podrias indicar lo que obtienes señalando la entrada y lo que deberias obtener. Te recomiendo leer [ask].

Comment: Falta señalar lo que obtienes ya que muchos no tienen a la mano una PC pero podrian ayudarte analizando tu código y tu respuesta.

Comment: Cuál es tu pregunta?

Answer (score 1):

No voy a analizar tu código ya que no explicas que esta haciendo tu código, en vez de ello voy a proponer una solucion.

Los pasos de mi algoritmo son los siguientes:

- Tener un generador de primos.
- Verificar si el primo n-ésimo es factor del número, si no lo es entonces se debe probar con el siguiente, si lo es seguir probando con ese número.
- El procedimiento termina cuando el resultado de dividir el numero es 1.

```py
import math


def es_primo(n):
    for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n) + 1)):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return n > 1


def generador_de_primos():
    yield 2
    n = 3
    while True:
        if es_primo(n):
            yield n
        n += 2


def factorizar(numero):
    factores = []
    g = generador_de_primos()
    factor = next(g)
    while numero != 1:
        if numero % factor == 0:
            numero //= factor
            factores.append(factor)
        else:
            factor = next(g)
    return factores

try:
    numero = int(input("Please, choose a number to factorize: "))
    factores = factorizar(numero)
    print(factores)
except ValueError as e:
    pass
```

**Actualización**

**¿Por qué no imprime los resultados?**

Analizemos paso a paso el problema:

1. La función `primeFactorization` es una función generadora como señala la docs:

> **generator**
>
> A function which returns a generator iterator. **It looks like
>   a normal function except that it contains yield expressions for
>   producing a series of values usable in a for-loop or that can be
>   retrieved one at a time with the next() function.**
>
> Usually refers to a generator function, but may refer to a generator
>   iterator in some contexts. In cases where the intended meaning isn’t
>   clear, using the full terms avoids ambiguity

<sup>enfasis mio</sup>

Asi que en este caso para corregir el problema puedes usar for-loop:

```
for e in primeFactorization():
    print(e)
```

Y obtienes:

```
2
2
```

2. Analicemos como varia `number` y `factor` añadiendo un print en el while.

```py
def primeFactorization():

    factor = 2
    number = int(input('Please, choose a number to factorize: '))

    while number != 1 and detector(factor):
        print(number, factor)
        if number % factor == 0:
            yield factor
            number = number / factor
        else:
            factor += 1

for e in primeFactorization():
    pass
```

Obteniendo:

```
100 2
50.0 2
25.0 2
25.0 3
```

Todo bien hasta el factor 3 pero en el caso 4 tu función `detector` retorna Falso por lo que ese es el otro problema.

Answer (score 1):

Aquí una solución según entendí el problema:

- Primero en la funcion `primeFactorization()` genero un arreglo con los números primos del número ingresado por el usuario
- Entonces en la función `factorizar(num, lista)` hallo el M.C.M. con los primos

.

```
def detector(num):
    cont = 0
    for i in range(1, num + 1):
        if num % i == 0:
            cont += 1
    if cont == 2 or num == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def primos(num):
    if num < 1:
        return False
    elif num == 2:
        return True
    else:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if num % i == 0:
                return False
        return True


def factorizar(num, lista):
    flag = True
    cont = num
    list = []
    for i in lista:
        while flag:
            cont = cont/i
            list.append(i)
            if cont % i != 0:
                flag=False
            if cont == num:
                break
        flag = True
    print("Lista del número factorizado por sus primos:", list)

def primeFactorization():
    factor = 2
    lista = []
    number = int(input('Please, choose a number to factorize: '))
    while factor <= number:
        if number % factor == 0 and primos(factor):
            lista.append(factor)
            factor += 1
        else:
            factor += 1

    print("lista de primos del numero ingresado:", lista)
    factorizar(number, lista)


primeFactorization()
```